# Действие при выборе части дерева в Treeview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

Подскажите, можно ли как-то сделать вызов функции при нажатии на определенный элемент дерева Treeview?
Вот само дерево:

```
root = Tk()
frame_tree=Frame(root)
treeview = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree)
treeview.insert('','0','material', text='Материал')
treeview.insert('material','0','coil', text='Катушка')
treeview.insert('coil','0','shell', text = 'Оболочка')
treeview.insert('coil','1','conductor', text = 'Проводник')
treeview.insert('conductor','0','cable', text = 'Кабель')
treeview.insert('material','1','size_pipeline', text='Типоразмер трубопровода')
treeview.insert('size_pipeline','0','aluminum_alloy', text='Алюминиевые сплавы')
treeview.item('material', open=True)
frame_tree.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side = 'left')
treeview.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Например я выбрал "Катушка", при нажатии на данный элемент должна выполниться функция, при нажатии на другой элемент должна выполниться другая функция.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло) можно было не уточнять в принципе, понял все сразу) Не было возможности ответить, к сожалению.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала просто пробуем привязаться к виртуальному событию `<<TreeviewSelect>>` объекта Treeview и получить информацию о выбранных элементах:

```
...

def on_select(event):
    print(event)
    print(treeview.selection())

treeview.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', on_select)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот 1]

В первый раз я просто выбрал катушку, во второй раз - с зажатой клавишей shift выбрал еще и "Типоразмер трубопровода" - в итоге выделенными оказались еще и все элементы между катушкой и типоразмером.

Будем считать, что нам нужен только первый выделенный элемент (для запрета выбора нескольких элементов можно при создании Treeview указать режим выделения "browse":
`treeview = ttk.Treeview(frame_tree, selectmode='browse')`)

Дальше есть несколько путей. Можно просто в if проверять какой элемент выбран, в зависимости от этого вызывать какую-то функцию, а можно, например, создать словарь, в котором нужным элементам сопоставлены функции (для сокращения кода делал через лямбды, но для более объемного кода имеет смысл создавать функции через `def`):

```
funcs_for_items = {
    'coil': lambda: print('Function 1'),
    'size_pipeline': lambda: print('Function 2')
}

def on_select(event):
    item = treeview.selection()[0]
    print(item)
    # Выбираем функцию из словаря, если элемента в словаре нет - выполняется действие по-умолчанию
    func = funcs_for_items.get(item, lambda: print('Default action'))
    func()

treeview.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', on_select)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот 2]