# Как взять данные из Treeview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Как сделать открытие окна при нажатии на строку Treeview Tkinter? То есть пользователь жмёт на строку с нужными ему данными и открывается новое окно, где те же самые данные что и в этой строке + всё остальное из БД. Как вывести данные из БД в отдельное окно я знаю, а вот как взять данные из выделенной строки в Treeview никак не пойму. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ в этом вопросе, возможно подойдет вам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955999/Действие-при-выборе-части-дерева-в-treeview

Comment: @insolor, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, нам нужно чтобы при выборе строки в дереве выполнялось какое то действие, при этом нужно получить доступ к данным в выбранной строке. Для реакции на выбор строки нужно привязаться к событию `<<TreeviewSelect>>` дерева (в принципе можно использовать другое событие, например двойной клик левой кнопкой мыши - `<Double-Button-1>`). Дальше через метод дерева `selection` нужно получить список id выделенных элементов. Дальше по id можно получить значения в строке.

```
def on_select(event):
    # вывод текстовых id всех выбранных строк
    # (их может быть несколько, если при создании дерева не было указано selectmode='browse')
    print(treeview.selection())

    # Если привязывались не к событию <<TreeviewSelect>>,
    # то тут нужно проверить, что вообще что-то выбрано:
    if not treeview.selection():
        return

    # Получаем id первого выделенного элемента
    selected_item = treeview.selection()[0]

    # Получаем значения в выделенной строке
    values = treeview.item(selected_item, option="values")
    print(values)


treeview.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', on_select)
```